# Erro com OnItemClickListen/AdapterView.OnItemClickListen

Tags: android

Não consigo consertar o seguinte código:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String[] atividades = new String[]{"Atividade 1", "Atividade 2"};

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, atividades);

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        listView.setOnClickListener(chamaAtividade());
    }

    public OnItemClickListener chamaAtividade() {
        return (new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent intent;
                switch (position) {
                    case 0:
                        intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Activity1.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Activity2.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
    }
    public void sair(View view) {
        finish();
    }
}
```

Aparece as seguintes mensagens de erro:

> Error:(30, 12) error: cannot find symbol class OnItemClickListener
>
> Error:(31, 21) error: cannot find symbol class OnItemClickListener
>
> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
>   Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Quando a gente muda o código como aparece na sugestão, muda onde tem `OnItemClickListener` para `AdapterView.OnItemClickListener`, depois da erro na linha que chama a função `chamaAtividade()`, e obviamente sugere a mudança da linha

```
listView.setOnClickListener(chamaAtividade());
```

para

```
listView.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) chamaAtividade());
```

Aparentemente era pra dar td certo, mas quando utilizo o celular pra executar o código, nem abre, diz que o aplicativo parou. O que pode ser?

As Activitys 'Activity1' e 'Activity' foram apenas criações de activitys em branco para fazer o teste e o arquivo activity_main.xml possui o seguinte código:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Sair"
    android:onClick="sair"/>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1">
</ListView>
```

Comment: provavelmente voce copiou o código de algum lugar e não importou as classes certas.. como estão os seus imports?

Comment: Modifiquei o conteúdo adicionando os imports

Comment: Hennan, você está criando um onItemClickListener para um onClickListener. São coisas diferentes. Tenta mudar pra listView.setOnItemClickListener no onCreate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O erro está ao setar o Click Listener.

No onCreate altere a linha

```
listView.setOnClickListener(chamaAtividade());
```

Por

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(chamaAtividade());
```

No método **chamaAtividade** altere o cabeçalho para:

```
public AdapterView.OnItemClickListener chamaAtividade(){ ... }
```

Comment: Pronto, era isso msm, muito obg pela ajuda, Haha

Comment: Não se esqueça de marcar a resposta como "aceita" :)